# Read CSV files from IP address to Android App

Tags: android, csv, android-studio, ip, androidplot

I am trying to create an Android App using Android Studio that has to first access an IP address. The IP address has many CSV files (in the form of an excel sheet). Based on the user's choice of the CSV file, certain columns of that CSV files must be plotted using Android Plot.

While I know how to handle plotting when given a set of values, how do I go about  accessing the CSV files and their data given the IP address? It is to be noted that the CSV files cannot be added to res folder since the files are added on a daily basis to the IP address.

Comment: `many CSV files (in the form of an excel sheet)` Well, indeed it's the opposite. An Excel sheet is "like a CSV". Anyway, just download the CSV files in a temporary folder and read them from there.

Comment: How to access a csv file on a computer with a certain ip address depends on the type of server you installed on that computer. So if you don't tell we cannot help.

Comment: Thank you, @BobMalooga. How do I create a temporary folder to specifically store just these files downloaded and not other downloads? I found a lot of examples for storing images but not many for documents.

Comment: How should it be different? A file is a file. It really doesn't matter which type of file it is. Unless you don't have to store it in a special location (i.e.: for the gallery or the Media Scanner to find it). Your app private data storage is just fine.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @BobMalooga